# Can't add .xib to my target in XCode

Tags: xcode, qt, xib

I've created a XCode project from a Qt pro file. I'd like to add a xib file to my project. However, once created, I cannot check the boxes in the "File inspector" under the "Target membership" section, so it is not compiled.

At runtime, the view controller's view associated with the xib is nil.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !

The target needs to have a "Copy bundle resource" build phase. To add one, click on "Add Copy Bundle Resource Build Phase" in the "Editor" > "Add Build Phase" menu with the target selected.